# secure file and folder names: function needed for validation

Tags: php, security

I am building an application where users can create folders and upload files. Of course, I need to validate the POST-Values so that a user cannot delete/overwrite files they aren't allowed to. What I am doing at the moment: When a file gets uploaded, I add a suffix to the file name, so "image.jpg" becomes "image.jpg-foo". The file paths are checked for "../" and "..\".

My question is: is this method secure enough, or is a user still able to get to another dir with another command? I don't want to change the file names to random characters as I don't wanna use a Database (the script has to be as small as possible).

My functions for the file path look like this (I user BetterFoldername for all user inputs) :

```
function endswith($string, $test) {
    $strlen = strlen($string);
    $testlen = strlen($test);
    if ($testlen > $strlen) 
        return false;
    return substr_compare($string, $test, $strlen - $testlen, $testlen) === 0;
}

function BetterFoldername($name) {
    $name = str_replace("../","",$name);
    $name = str_replace("..\\","",$name);
    $name = str_replace("//","/",$name);
    $name = str_replace("\\\\","\\",$name);
    if(endswith($name, "/") || endswith($name, "\\")) {
        $name = substr($name, 0, -1);
    }
    if (preg_match("/[^\sA-Za-z0-9_.\/\-]/", $name)) {
         exit("An error occured!");  
    }
    return $name;
}
```

Comment: According to me for each user try to create a directory and permission. and also before upload a file try to put some security like encode decode or password permission. For each user this will be different.

Comment: There is a password check for each user - didn't mention it, sorry. The session is checked every time the users try to change or read anything. Users have their "own" folders and can get access to other users' folders when both confirm they want to.

Comment: Give only read permission to user for other users folders and file.